# Random forest and model predictions

Tags: r, random-forest, prediction, cart

I have a working random forest model (classification tree) in R that I made with a training dataset. I used the predict function with a verification dataset:

```
> predict(RF_model, Verif_samp)
```

The predicted values this produces must have been put into some kind of formula made by the random forest model? I'm wondering how to see what happened here - I would like to know if there is any kind of overall model or formula that a random forest creates (used by predict), and if so, how it would be viewed in R.

Answer (score 1):

A random forest is a set of decision trees. There's no prediction "formula" to speak of in the sense of an ordinary regression; a random forest prediction is the output of a bunch of trees. *[Elements of Statistical Learning](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/local.ftp/Springer/OLD/ESLII_print4.pdf)* provides more information about how random forests work.

I'm not sure what random forest implementation you're using. If it's `randomForest`,  then you can extract particular trees from the random forest object `rf.obj` using `getTree`. So

```
getTree(rf.obj, k=1)
```

will give you the first tree, `k=2` will give you the second, and so on. The help page for `getTree` explains the output.

In a classification problem, the predict function gives each tree a vote, and plurality rules. This is, effectively, an average over many decision trees. A tie is broken at random.